# Почему инженер, но реверс-инжиниринг?

Tags: выбор-слов, недопустимая-метка

Почему "инж**е**н**е**р" через две **е**, но "[реверс-инж**и**н**и**ринг](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0)" через две **и**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Инженер от французского [ingénieur](https://lexicography.online/etymology/krylov/%D0%B8/%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80)(инженьё, если я не ошибаюсь), а название профы "реверс-инжиниринг" - калька с английского [engineering](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/trudnosti?layout=item&id=36_95) (инжиниринг). Разные исходники для кальки, но по сути одно от одного [смысла](https://www.etymonline.com/word/*gene-?ref=etymonline_crossreference).

ну и, конечно, должно писаться инжЕнЕринг, а еще лучше инженерия - реверс-инженерия, ну или "реверс-инжиниринг — он же обратное проектирование", но у нас сейчас, увы, [рунглиш](https://lurkmore.wtf/%D0%A0%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%88).